# Microsoft Outlook 2011 memory leak

Tags: ms-office, memory-leak

Can anyone tell me why Outlook is using between 650Mb and 1.2Gb of memory?

I've googled but can't find anything. Outlook isn't crashing (Seems to be the main problem others are having) but my whole system is hanging.

If it was up to me I'd uninstall, but this is a work machine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a simple Archiving, to reduce the active file size.

Comment: Should add that this is connecting to an Exchange server not using POP.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely due to your particular database file.

Have you tried making a new user account and checking Outlook with an empty local mail store? You could also go in and switch user's but I don't recall the steps needed to close the main outlook database and make a new one so I'll leave that for someone else to edit in or answer.